# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a an problem with my .NET 5.0 Web API project in which I 'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3.  in this project, I need to use some .Dll references of some old projects used Entity framework 6.0.0. I have got the exception "Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0 ......" without I have updated Entity framwork in all projects to be version 6.1.3. Please help me!

This is Project.json:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
"EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
"EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta6",
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta6",
"structuremap": "3.1.6.186",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta6",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
"System.ServiceModel.Duplex": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
"System.ServiceModel.NetTcp": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
"System.ServiceModel.Security": "4.0.0-beta-23019"

},

"commands": {
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
"ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
},

"frameworks": {
"dnx451": {
"dependencies": {
"CuttingEdge.Conditions": "1.0.0-*",
"Quartz": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.Application": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.Finance": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.Infrastructure": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.QuartzScheduler": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.ServiceDesks": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.Utilities": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.WCFMock": "1.0.0-*"
},
"frameworkAssemblies": {
"System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0"
}
}
},

"publishExclude": [
"node_modules",
"bower_components",
"**.xproj",
"**.user",
"**.vspscc"
],
"exclude": [
"wwwroot",
"node_modules",
"bower_components"
]
}
```

I have update the Entity Framework in the old projects to be version 6.1.3 and setup in the App.config:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

But the above exception still occurs. Please help me!

This is the full error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
```

Comment: Could you please let us know what comes after `Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0 `?

Comment: That exception occurs when I using StructureMap to call the Object Context from the Dll of the old project: 
_accountService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IAccountService>();

Comment: What I meant is: can you show us the full error rather than replacing the rest with `......`?

Comment: I have posted the full error. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are loading both EF6 and EF7 (you have both versions in your `project.json`). You should either downgrade your `EntityFramework.SqlServer` to version 6, or upgrade your `EntityFramework` to version 7.

In other words, either use EF6 or EF7, but don't mix assemblies from different versions.

```
"EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
"EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta6",
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta6",
```

Comment: Please show me what version for "EntityFramework.SqlServer" and "EntityFramework.Commands" Should I use. I just have from 7.0.0-beta1 to 7.0.0-beta7. I'm using 7.0.0-beta6 because only it supports the method ".AddSqlServer()" for using this code: 

    services.AddMvc();
            var connectionString = Configuration.Get("Data:BrokerageSimulatorEntities:ConnectionString");           
            services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer().AddDbContext<BrokerageSimulatorDbContext>(options =>
             {
                 options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
             });